# Build Template for ASP.NET Core (.NET 4.6.2)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

On VSTS, I'm trying to define a build definition for my ASP.NET Core app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2

I see these two templates on VSTS Build but not sure what the difference between the two is and which one I should use.

[image]

I tried both and got different errors. Which build template is a good start for me? My app currently is a very simple "Hello World" app but it does have a couple of class library projects in it. I did that to simulate what my app will look like when I'm done.

So, my solution looks like this:

-- ASP.NET Core app (Targeting .NET 4.6.2)

-- Class Library 1 (Targeting .NET 4.6.2)

-- Class Library 2 (Targeting .NET 4.6.2)

Both class libraries are the classic type -- see below

[image]

UPDATE:
I tried following this article which is really for an ASP.NET solution built on .Net Core.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

However, I'm getting the error in Step 2: dotnet restore:

```
Errors in C:\a\1\s\Dev\src\MyProject\project.json
2016-11-07T17:17:33.3792225Z     Unable to resolve 'ClassLibrary1' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
2016-11-07T17:17:33.3792225Z     Unable to resolve 'ClassLibrary2' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'
```

What modifications do I need to make so that I can apply these steps to my project?

UPDATE 2:
Here's my project.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "ClassLibrary2": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE 3:
This is the current set of tasks in the build definition. This is directly from ASP.NET Build (PREVIEW) except I removed the test step and changed the NuGet version to 3.5.0 - build 1938 (rc2). Also, the MSBuild arguments are follows:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the error message, the error is in the project.json. Share detail code of your project.json. Did you add ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 references to .net core project? The target framework is incompatible, how did you add references.

Comment: Just added my project.json file to the original post. It's an ASP.NET Core app but it targets the full .NET Framework. I added the projects through "References" and Visual Studio added them to project.json automatically.

Comment: How did you create the .Net Core project targeting to 4.6.2, the project.json file you provided does not work at my side.

Comment: Simply created a fresh ASP.NET Core project targeting .Net framework using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and all the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet restore command can't restore local project dependency. More information, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3199) thread.

My steps:

1. Create a build definition with ASP.NET Build (PREVIEW) template
2. Change nugget version to 3.5.0
   [image]

Note: The Hosted Build Agent includes .Net Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling, so you need to use corresponding version of SDK.

global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I use .Net Core 1.0 at all? All the projects in the solution are using the full .Net Framework 4.6.2

Comment: Still giving me the same error in dotnet restore i.e. unable to resolve class libraries.

Comment: @Sam Dotnet restore can't restore local project reference, using Nuget 3.5 could solve this issue. I updated my answer.

Comment: After making the changes, the build succeeds BUT doesn't produce any artifacts. Here's the message: Directory 'C:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Comment: I just updated the original post and added a screen shot of the current tasks in my build definition.

Comment: @Sam you can refer to this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure) to publish web app via dotnet publish command (Command line step) and zip files via archive file step. These two steps could be replaced with .Net Core (Preview) step (Command: publish)

Comment: The issue right now is that the build is not producing any artifacts

Comment: @Sam Do you add .Net Core (Preview) build step? If so, you need to add Copy Files step to copy necessary file to artifact folder.

Comment: I do not have the .NET Core (Preview) step. The steps I have are in my UPDATE 3 in the original post.

Comment: @Sam 1. Remove MSBuild arguments from visual studio build step. 2. Add Command Line step (Tool: dotnet; argument: publish -c $(BuildConfiguration); Advanced, Working folder: [your working folder(source folder) ] 3. Add Archive Files step to create zip file with necessary root files to Artifact folder. More information, refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure#define-a-deployment-build

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I think we're pretty close to getting it to work. In Archive Files step if I set the Root folder to exactly what the article says, I get an error in the build saying no such folder exists. My app is an ASP.NET Core app but it's built on .NET Framework so I suspect the "netcoreapp1.0" folder does not exist. If I remove that I still get the same error. If I point to the root of my src directory, the build works but it includes all source files e.g. HomeController.cs and consequently the web app fails with HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Comment: @Sam The simple way is that you could run dotnet publish command in your local machine, then check the published file location. After that, modify your build definition. (For me: bin\Debug\net462\win7-x64\publish)

Comment: @Sam You also could check build log. (e.g. Published to C:\a\1\s\CoreWithLibrary\src\WebCoreFramework\bin\Debug\net462\win7-x64\publish)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get back to you sooner. I have not yet resolved it. I'll try it later tonight and get back to you.

Comment: @Sam What's the result now?